# LeetCode Word Break, fail on Online Judge but pass Online test

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, undefined-behavior, word-break

I met a problem when I was doing leetcode 139, word break.

Given a string s and a dictionary of words dict, determine if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words. (each dictionary word can be used multiple times.)

For example, given
s = "leetcode",
dict = ["leet", "code"].

Return true because "leetcode" can be segmented as "leet code".

I use basic dynamic programming algorithm, but may implement it in a different way from the popular one on the internet.
Here is the code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool wordBreak(string s, unordered_set<string>& wordDict) {
        int strlen = s.length();
        if(0 == strlen)  return true;
        vector<bool> sepable(false, strlen);
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen; ++i) {
            if(wordDict.count(s.substr(0,i+1)) > 0) {
                sepable[i] = true;
                continue;
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                if(sepable[j] && wordDict.count(s.substr(j+1,i-j)) > 0) {
                    sepable[i] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return sepable[strlen-1];
    }
};
```

When I ran online judge, it fails at the test:" "aaaaaaa" ["aaaa","aa"]", my code output true, the expected answer is false. However, if I run it on online test, it gives the right output. Also, it works fine on my own virtual machine with clang++.

The difference between online judge and online test is that each online test is only one test. Online judge contains many tests and will fail if anyone of the tests fails. So the problem of my code may lay like this: at some test other than the "aaaaaaa", it gives the right output but cause some potential problem. And that is why my code will fail on "aaaaaaa". However, if I just run this single test, it is fine.

The leetcode website says it may because my code has some undefined behaviors. The previous test case may influence the latter one. I don't know what are all the previous test case and didn't expect anyone here know about it. But I think as long as there are problems in my code, someone can find it.

I think the question is pretty clear this time.

Comment: Unless you post a [MCVE] no one will be able to reproduce this.

Comment: It makes no use if I write a test case for it that can make everyone test on their own machines. As I said, it works well on my local vm, and I believe it will work on others' local machines. But it cannot pass the leetcode online judge. That is the problem.

Comment: Why do you think anyone would make that effort? I gave you a good hint about asking a valid and good question here. So if you don't care, I won't either ... Regarding online judge, that's very often misunderstood that anyone here would have knowledge about their inner workings. So basically your question as is is unanswerable.

Comment: I agree with πάντα ῥεῖ, but I would like to add that it would be better to edit your question so that it includes the problem statement, so that we don't have to rely on an external link. Apart from this, the statement isn't really clear. For example, can dictionary words be reused? Moreover, I don't get the difference between online test and online judge. In any case I would say that for `"aaaaaaa" ["aaaa","aa"]` I would expect the answer to be false, so I agree with the online judge. Why do you think it's true? How can you split 7 letters in groups of 4 and 2?

Comment: I think it's quite clear this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line parameters are of wrong order `vector<bool> sepable(false, strlen);` it should be `vector<bool> sepable(strlen,false);`the length of the vector comes first then the default value and false is implicitly converted to int so the length is set to 0 that gave the undefined behavior

Comment: Thanks! That's the problem! I will definitely look up API more carefully next time.